# Encryption [STANDARD] Ubuntu?

Tags: security, encryption, home-directory

During the installation of Ubuntu I ticked the encrypt system and encrypt home folder boxes. But I have heard that it is foolish to encrypt the home folder when I already have encrypted my system.

So where can I see what is encrypted [and how can I decrypt my Home folder]? And I also want a better encryption of my system because I as a businessman have a lot of sensible data. So how to increase the security of the encryption of my system?

And what encrypter is the best and free for Linux [most secure]?

**Summary:**

> How to administrate the standard encryption and how to make the
>   encryption of the system so secure as it can be under Linux? How to
>   delete the encryption on my home folder [and how to control what is
>   encrypted on my pc]? And what program is free and the best for Linux
>   [most secure]?

Kind regards and thank you very much for help!
Basilius

Answer (score 2):

For more information on the "Home Directory" encryption, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory .

For more information on the "Whole Disk" encryption, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems .

If the computer is used exclusively by a single person, then yes, "Home Directory" encryption offers very little additional security if "Whole Disk" is in place.  If it's shared between multiple people, however, either you all share the password for the whole-disk encryption, or you have separate keys that each unlock the whole-disk encryption.

If you do have "Home Directory" encryption, it's not actually the case that your entire home directory is encrypted.  Rather, you have a directory `~/Private` that you can store files (or symlink dot-files) in, backed by directory `~/.Private`.  Someone who can become root on the system can see rough file sizes, last-modification times, and directory-tree depth within that directory.  Furthermore, if you use a program to edit one of those files, it's possible that unencryted sensitive material could be written to swap or temporary files.

To "delete the encryption", just move files out of `~/Private` with `mv`.